# "expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token" error--C++

Tags: c++, syntax, compilation, token

NOTE: I don't think this is a duplicate of the billion other questions about this. I have looked over the code in question and it is not a syntax error (I think).

I have the following function:

```
char init_fundementals()
{
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(uint16_t), read_uint16, write_uint16);
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(char*), read_cstr, write_cstr);
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(uint32_t), read_uint32, write_uint32);
    return 'z';
}
```

Where all of the `write_`... and `read_`... function declared earlier in the file. The file is a header (because all I do is include it). There is a reason why this returns `z` always. It is a hack, and one I am not sure works. The compiler gives me the following error:

```
fundemental_bin_types.h:70:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
fundemental_bin_types.h:71:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
fundemental_bin_types.h:72:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
```

This header includes the header for the class `BinIO`.

BinIO.h:

```
#ifndef BINIO_H
#define BINIO_H
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<fstream> fstream_ptr;
class BinIO {
public:
    BinIO();
    static void AddBinType(type_info t_name, void(*reader)(fstream_ptr, void*), void(*writer)(fstream_ptr, void*));
protected:
    static map<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)> typemap_r;
    static map<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)> typemap_w;
};
#endif  /* BINIO_H */
```

BinIO.cpp:

```
#include "BinIO.h"
BinIO::typemap_r=map<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)>;
BinIO::typemap_w=map<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)>;
BinIO::BinIO() {
}
BinIO::AddBinType(type_info t_name, void(*)(fstream_ptr,void*) reader, void(*)(fstream_ptr,void*) writer)
{
    typemap_r.insert(pair<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)>(t_name.name(), reader));
    typemap_w.insert(pair<char*, void(*)(fstream_ptr, void*)>(t_name.name(), writer));
}
```

fundamental_bin_types.h:

```
#ifndef FUNDEMENTAL_BIN_TYPES_H
#define FUNDEMENTAL_BIN_TYPES_H
#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "BinIO.h"
using namespace std;
void read_uint32(fstream_ptr in, void* out)
{
    char data[sizeof(uint32_t)];
    (*in).read(data, 4);
    *((uint32_t*)out)=ntohl(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(data));
}
void write_uint32(fstream_ptr out, void* in)
{
    (*out).write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(htonl(*(uint32_t*)in)), sizeof(uint32_t));
}
//
void read_cstr(fstream_ptr in, void* out)
{
    char* buff;
    char* size;
    (*in).read(size, sizeof(size_t));
    (*in).read(buff, reinterpret_cast<size_t>(size));
    *((char*)out)=*buff;
}
void write_cstr(fstream_ptr out, void* in)
{
    (*out).write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(in), sizeof(size_t));
    (*out).write((char*)in, strlen((char*)in));
}
//
void read_uint16(fstream_ptr in, void* out)
{
    char data[sizeof(uint16_t)];
    (*in).read(data, sizeof(uint16_t));
    *((uint16_t*)out)=ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data));
}
void write_uint16(fstream_ptr out, void* in)
{
    (*out).write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(htons(*((uint16_t*)in))), sizeof(uint16_t));
}
//
void read_bindata(fstream_ptr in, void* out)
{
    uint32_t* size;
    read_uint32(in, size);
    out=new char[*size];
    (*in).read((char*)out, *size);
}
void write_bindata(fstream_ptr out, void* in)
{
    char buff[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        buff[i]=*(((char*)in)+i);
    }
    (*out).write(buff, 4);
    (*out).write(((char*)in)+4, reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(buff));
}
void init_fundementals()
{
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(uint16_t), read_uint16, write_uint16);
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(char*), read_cstr, write_cstr);
    BinIO.AddBinType(typeid(uint32_t), read_uint32, write_uint32);
}
#endif  /* FUNDEMENTAL_BIN_TYPES_H */
```

Does someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `::` to access the static function:

```
BinIO::AddBinType(typeid(uint16_t), read_uint16, write_uint16);
```

Answer (score 2):

The **scope resolution operator** in C++ is `::`, and that's what you need to use to access static methods or members, unlike Java or C#:

```
BinIO::AddBinType
```

instead of

```
BinIO.AddBinType
```